# как расшифровать https и его смотреть

Tags: https, tcpdump

Вопрос в том чтобы анализировать трафик https по типу как ngrep, т.е. видеть что в пакетах как минимум заголовки. При этом трафик не нужно изменять, а просто расшифровать и посмотреть, желательно в режиме онлайн, но можно варинт даже с захватом дампа. Важный момент, это легитимно и есть все сертификаты сервера.

Comment: https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/49245/how-to-log-https-headers

Comment: [неплохая статья по теме](https://habr.com/ru/company/billing/blog/261301/) по wireshark'у...